# Differentiation algebra with index notation

Tags: special-relativity, differentiation

Consider $p_\mu p^\mu$ and let us differentiate it with respect to $p^\nu$. Then,
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial p^\nu}(p_\mu p^\mu) = p^\mu \eta_{\mu \sigma}\delta^\sigma_\nu + p_\mu \delta_\nu^\mu = 2 p_\nu$$
But if you consider the relation $p_\mu p^\mu =-m^2$, then
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial p^\nu}(p_\mu p^\mu) = \frac{\partial}{\partial p^\nu} (-m^2) = 0$$
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The partial derivative of a function is defined like this:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,y) := \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+\epsilon,y)-f(x,y)}{\epsilon}$$
In words, when computing the partial derivative of an expression with respect to $x$, you vary $x$ **while holding everything else fixed** and compute the corresponding difference quotient.  For example,

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x^2+y^2)=2x \qquad \frac{\partial}{\partial y}(x^2+y^2)=2y$$

On the other hand, the expression $x^2+y^2=1$ defines a relationship between $x$ and $y$.  If you want this expression to remain true, then $x$ and $y$ are not independent of one another; you generally **cannot** vary one without simultaneously varying the other.  Naively differentiating both sides yields

$$2x = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x^2+y^2) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(1) = 0$$
$$\implies x=0, y=\pm 1$$

What you're doing here is the following.  You are computing the rate of change of the quantity $x^2+y^2$ by varying $x$ **and holding $y$ fixed** - and *also* restricting your attention to the points which satisfy the constraint $x^2+y^2=1$.

In this sense it may be surprising that you obtained *any* solutions at all; the reason you *do* is that at the points $(x,y)=(0,\pm 1)$, varying $x$ by an infinitesimal amount $\delta$ corresponds to a variation in $y$ which goes like $\delta^2$ (i.e. the first order variation in $y$ vanishes).  This is another way of saying that $y$ is *stationary* (with respect to variations in $x$) at those points.

---

If you understand this, then the answer to your question is basically identical.  The expression $p_\mu p^\mu = \eta_{\mu\nu} p^\mu p^\nu$ is just a quadratic expression in the variables $p^0,p^1,p^2,$ and $p^3$.  In principle, it can take any value, and differentiating it with respect to $p^\mu$ yields $2p_\mu$, as you say.

On the other hand, for massive particles the 4-momentum is not completely arbitrary; it is constrained by the [on-shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_shell_and_off_shell) constraint $p_\mu p^\mu=-m^2$.  As a result, you generically *cannot* vary any individual component of the momentum without varying the others.  The only time you *can* is when $p_\mu=0$, for the same reason as the simpler example given above.